# Auto Shutdown, after giving cancel option to user

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, batch, shutdown

I would like to setup a script or a tool on some computers for automatic shutdown, at a given time, say  late in the night, when users have left for the day (forgetting to shutdown the computer). It should also force a shutdown if some processes don't respond. However, if a user happens to be at the computer using it, I want to be able to show a Cancel button, for say, 30 seconds, so that the user can cancel the shutdown, like the cute way in which uTorrent does.

I have checked Daxtar Shutdown (a good tool but without scheduling, nor a batch file construct facility) and Simple Shutdown Scheduler ( a good one, but no cancel option ). I have also looked at the top questions tagged with shutdown in this forum. I have also tried using the shutdown script inside a Windows batch file, but not able to find a way to accomplish a key 'user delight' requirement, that is the 'option to be able to cancel it in N seconds'.  I have no 'remote' requirement. Preferably, I want to be able to use it in Windows XP-SP3 and Windows 7.

What script, batch file or tool or a combo of these can accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [this one a shot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331428/how-to-ask-for-batch-file-user-input-with-a-timeout/12787881#12787881), I didn't have time to build one to do this another way but this should suffice I suppose . . .

**Note** that in the `for /l %%N in (30`the number here is the amount of seconds to wait so it's `30` for 30 seconds.

> ```
> @echo off
> setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
> for /l %%N in (30 -1 1) do (
>   set /a "min=%%N/60, sec=%%N%%60, n-=1"
>   if !sec! lss 10 set sec=0!sec!
>   cls
>   choice /c:CN1 /n /m "Restart in !min!:!sec! - Press N to Restart Now, or C to Cancel. " /t:1 /d:1
>   if not errorlevel 3 goto :break
> )
> cls
> echo RESTART in 0:00 - Press N to Restart Now, or C to Cancel.
> :break
> if errorlevel 2 (shutdown /r /t 10) else echo restart Canceled
> ```
>
> <sub>[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12331428/how-to-ask-for-batch-file-user-input-with-a-timeout/12787881#12787881)</sub>

Comment: Super! It works like a charm on Windows 7. While I haven't had the chance to try on Windows XP yet, (I read choice.exe doesn't work on XP ?), it's good still.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will find this [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-schedule-computer-to-shut-down-at-a-certain/800ed207-f630-480d-8c92-dff2313c193b) helpful. Please go through it and see if it any help.

Link of the [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/how-to-schedule-computer-to-shut-down-at-a-certain/800ed207-f630-480d-8c92-dff2313c193b).

> Usage: shutdown [/i | /l | /s | /r | /g | /a | /p | /h | /e] [/f]
>       [/m \computer][/t xxx][/d [p|u:]xx:yy [/c "comment"]]

...

> ```
> /t xxx     Set the time-out period before shutdown to xxx seconds.
>            The valid range is 0-315360000 (10 years), with a default of 30.
>            If the timeout period is greater than 0, the /f parameter is
>            implied.
> /c "comment" Comment on the reason for the restart or shutdown.
>            Maximum of 512 characters allowed.
> /f         Force running applications to close without forewarning users.
>            The /f parameter is implied when a value greater than 0 is
>            specified for the /t parameter.
> ```

Thank you. Let me know if anything.

Comment: The page points to a /t option that provides for a timeout, within which the shutdown can be cancelled. Good thing, thanks. I am looking for a little more, a way to show a Cancel button so that user can invoke the option provided by /t.